# Cannot connect MS access database (*.accdb) with python 3.6 (Anaconda 64 bits)

Tags: python, database, ms-access

I am trying to import data from MS access database (*.accdb extension) with python but getting the error

> pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data
>   source name not found and no default driver specified (0)
>   (SQLDriverConnect)')

Looked into several links but not able to find a solution.

I am using python 64 bits.

When I go to create a new data source with ODBC data source administrator (32 bits), I cannot find MS acess driver *.accdb.

With ODBC data source administrator (64 bits), only SQL server is available.

Comment: Please show pyodbc connection line. And possibly your MS Office is installed as 32-bit.

Comment: You can use the [AceOdbcCheck](https://github.com/gordthompson/AceOdbcCheck) script to see if you have a valid Access ODBC install. If not, then you can download the 64-bit version [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might need to either use Python in a 32-bit distribution or Ms Access in a 64-bit distribution. You can download it from this link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13255